# 8 pinned IC using Circuit-Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I can't seem to find a simple way to create and move around ICs with CircuitTikz. Specifically I want to place an OP-amp IC somewhere, say (5,5), and have the corresponding pins relative to those coordinates, say pin 1 at (5,5.5), pin 2 at (5,6), etc) so I can place it somewhere and relatively quickly connect it to the rest of the circuit. But I don't understand how to do this.

Here is an image of the OP-amp I'm trying to implement.
[image]

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any support for generic ICs in circuitikz.  If there was I'd expect to address the pins by anchors called things like `pin 1` as with logic gates etc (p32 of the manual).  To do it properly would require quite a lot of effort; I reckon you'd do it parametrically for an arbitrary number of pins There is, however, support for op-amps (using the right-pointing triangle symbol, which is good for circuit logic, much  less good for wiring instructions)

Comment: BTW I'd expect the [notch to be at the top near pin 1](http://images.slideplayer.com/19/5883947/slides/slide_5.jpg)

Comment: this is quit complex image which you should define for example with small pictures (`\pic`). searching on the site will show you some similar solutions.

Comment: @ChrisH you are correct. I updated the figure now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a standard 8 pin DIP from [my web site](http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm).  Anchors include p1 through p8.  The size is adjusted using `[pin spacing=...]`.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Compass}% define anchors for compass points
{\anchor{north east}{\northeast}
\anchor{south west}{\southwest}
\anchor{north}{\pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@up}{\northeast}\pgfpoint{0cm}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
\anchor{north west}{\pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@up}{\northeast}\pgfextractx{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\southwest}\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
\anchor{west}{\pgfextractx{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\sosuthwest}\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0cm}}
\anchor{south}{\pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@down}{\southwest}\pgfpoint{0cm}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
\anchor{south east}{\pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@down}{\southwest}\pgfextractx{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\northeast}\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
\anchor{east}{\pgfextractx{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\northeast}\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0cm}}}

% ************************** multipoles *****************************

\ctikzset{multipoles/.is family}
\ctikzset{multipoles/pin spacing/.initial = 5mm} % default value
\ctikzset{multipoles/gate spacing/.initial = 1cm} % default value

\pgfkeys{/tikz/pin spacing/.initial = 0mm}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/pin spacing/.default = 0mm}

\newlength{\IClen}  % scale factor
\newcommand{\pinsize}{\ifdim\IClen<3.5mm \tiny \else \scriptsize \fi}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/gate spacing/.initial = 0cm}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/gate spacing/.default = 0cm}

\newlength{\GateSpacing}

% ***************************** dip 8 *********************************
% anchors pin1 - pin8

\pgfdeclareshape{dip8}{
\anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}    % within the node, (0,0) is the center

\anchor{text}   % this is used to center the text in the node
    {\pgfpoint{-.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}{-.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox}}

\savedmacro{\resize}{   % called automatically
 \setlength{\IClen}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pin spacing}} % from node[]
 \ifdim\IClen=0mm \setlength{\IClen}
  {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/multipoles/pin spacing}} \fi    % from \ctikzset{}
}
\savedanchor\icpina{\pgfpoint{-1.5\IClen}{-1.25\IClen}} % pin 1
\anchor{p1}{\icpina}
\savedanchor\icpinb{\pgfpoint{-.5\IClen}{-1.25\IClen}}  % pin 2
\anchor{p2}{\icpinb}
\savedanchor\icpinc{\pgfpoint{.5\IClen}{-1.25\IClen}}   % pin 3
\anchor{p3}{\icpinc}
\savedanchor\icpind{\pgfpoint{1.5\IClen}{-1.25\IClen}}  % pin 4
\anchor{p4}{\icpind}
\savedanchor\icpine{\pgfpoint{1.5\IClen}{1.25\IClen}}   % pin 5
\anchor{p5}{\icpine}
\savedanchor\icpinf{\pgfpoint{.5\IClen}{1.25\IClen}}    % pin 6
\anchor{p6}{\icpinf}
\savedanchor\icping{\pgfpoint{-.5\IClen}{1.25\IClen}}   % pin 7
\anchor{p7}{\icping}
\savedanchor\icpinh{\pgfpoint{-1.5\IClen}{1.25\IClen}}  % pin 8
\anchor{p8}{\icpinh}

\savedanchor{\northeast}{\pgfpoint{2\IClen}{1.25\IClen}}
\savedanchor{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{-2\IClen}{-1.25\IClen}}
\Compass% standard anchors

\foregroundpath{ % border and pin numbers are drawn here
 \pgfsetlinewidth{.1\IClen} % line thickness 
 \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}
 \pgfusepath{draw}  %draw rectangle
 \pgfsetlinewidth{.06\IClen} % line thickness 
 \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2\IClen}{-.6\IClen}}
 \pgfpatharc{-90}{90}{.6\IClen}
 \pgfusepath{draw}  %draw semicircle
 \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{-1.5\IClen}{-1.1\IClen}}]{\pinsize 1}
 \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{-.5\IClen}{-1.1\IClen}}]{\pinsize 2}
 \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{.5\IClen}{-1.1\IClen}}]{\pinsize 3}
 \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{1.5\IClen}{-1.1\IClen}}]{\pinsize 4}
 \pgftext[top,at={\pgfpoint{1.5\IClen}{1.1\IClen}}]{\pinsize 5}
 \pgftext[top,at={\pgfpoint{.5\IClen}{1.1\IClen}}]{\pinsize 6}
 \pgftext[top,at={\pgfpoint{-.5\IClen}{1.1\IClen}}]{\pinsize 7}
 \pgftext[top,at={\pgfpoint{-1.5\IClen}{1.1\IClen}}]{\pinsize 8}
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\node[dip8,rotate=-90] (T) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Nice website. A lot of useful figures and components.