# Custom Integrated Circuits with CircuiTikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

I would like to recreate an Integrated Circuit like this one:

[image]

I have written this with CircuiTikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{multipoles/thickness=4}
    \ctikzset{multipoles/thickness=4}
     \ctikzset{multipoles/external pins thickness=2}
     \draw (0,0) node[dipchip,num pins=14,hide numbers,external pins 
      width=0.3,external pad fraction=4, rotate=90]{\rotatebox{-90}{7404}};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

As you can see I have used the last release of CircuiTikz, [this is were you can get it](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/).

I would like to know how to write the pin number (1,2,...,14) in those little rectangles (the pin itself) like in the photo above and have enough space to write the name of the pin like "Vcc" or "Gnd".

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416631/8-pinned-ic-using-circuit-tikz/416677?r=SearchResults&s=2|26.5556#416677, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416631/8-pinned-ic-using-circuit-tikz/416677?r=SearchResults&s=2|26.5556#416677,  and http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the "border pin" anchors (I have enlarged a bit the pads to fit the numbers).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{multipoles/thickness=4}
    \ctikzset{multipoles/thickness=4}
     \ctikzset{multipoles/external pins thickness=2}
     \draw (0,0) node[dipchip,num pins=14,hide numbers,external pins
     width=0.3,external pad fraction=3, rotate=90](C){\rotatebox{-90}{7404}};

      \foreach \pin in {1,...,7} \node[font=\tiny, below] at (C.bpin \pin) {\pin};
      \foreach \pin in {8,...,14} \node[font=\tiny, above] at (C.bpin \pin) {\pin};
      \node [font=\tiny\ttfamily, above] at(C.bpin 7) {Gnd};
      \node [font=\tiny\ttfamily, below] at(C.bpin 14) {Vcc};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the snippet above]